# Find first occurrence of an integer in a sorted list with duplicates

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

This code prints the first occurence of element 'k' in the array properly but the question I'm doing wants me to print -1 if the element 'k' is entirely not present in the array. I know its easy but I'm just stuck and its frustatiting any help?

```java
n = sc.nextInt();
k = sc.nextInt();
int arr[] = new int[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
}
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    if(arr[i]==k) {
        System.out.println(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please always include the language/technology tag you're using. This will engage more relevant people and disengage those who are deliberately ignoring some specific ones.

Comment: Actually, what you are asking in the title, and what you are asking in the post body, are two different questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int findOccurenceOfElemet(int[] a, int k) {
        if(a.length == 0) {
            return -1;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if(a[i] == k) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        
        //return -1 if element not found
        return -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Arrays#binarySearch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(int%5B%5D,int)):

```
int firstIndexOf(int[] sortedArray, int x) {
    int p = Arrays.binarySearch(sortedArray, x);
    if (p < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    while (p > 0 && sortedArray[p - 1] == x) {
        --p;
    }
    return p;
}
```

Binary search splits the searched range in half repetively looking in which half to continue. It returns either the found position or the complement (~p) of the insert position.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking in the title, and what you are asking in the post body, are two **different** questions; however, if we will follow your question's body, that has **nothing** to do with *binary search*, and introducing boolean flag would get you what you are asking for:

```java
boolean notFound = true;

for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    if(arr[i] == k) {
        System.out.println(i);
        notFound = false;
        break;
    }
}

if(notFound) System.out.println("-1");
```